# How to make orthographic text always shown/TopMost?

Tags: opengl, text, freetype, text-rendering, topmost

I have created an OpenGL text rendered with an orthographic projection and a black cube rendered with a perspective projection.

So I was following this tutorial on [Text Rendering in LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering) and I've made a good wrapper around the whole code to make it readable and less. And everything is fine except for the problem that when I tried to render an object with the text which isn't in that tutorial, the text passes through that object like in this GIF below...

[image: OPENGL TEXT PASSES THROUGH OBJECTS]

Any good Ideas on how to make the text always on screen? The tutorial I was following didn't state how to overcome such a thing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable [depth testing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) (`glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`) before rendering the text.